# WPF/PrismV4: Can't load in Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

WTF, I'm getting a gazillion errors. Saying a bunch of "Solution Folders are not supported in this version of the application".

I'm trying to open this: StackTraderRI_Desktop.sln (the main stock trader example app that comes with Prism).

This is a long shot, but has anyone figured why this is happening? Note, I'm using the express edition not professional.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of "a gazillion errors" how about the first two?  Or maybe an error that pertains to the solution file, at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the pro or higher version then. This usually because in one solution there's several different type of projects, for example one is a simple desktop client and the other one is a web service.